# How to pull an unspecific string from within another string?

Tags: vb.net, string

So I've been teaching myself VB.NET and stack overflow has been lots of help so far, but there was a something that I needed done that I haven't been able to find. 
With the API I use, I get a return value of something like this:

```
<user>
<user_name>example</user_name>
<user_website>http://myawesomesite.com</user_website>
<user_email>oh@dear.com</user_email>
<user_location>New York</user_location>
</user>
```

I want to be able to pull out the data from within all of the tags, and assign them to strings, but I don't know how. I need to split it after a ">" and before a "<", does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: The data you're getting in as XML. Search for XML parsing or deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either `XElement` or `XmlDocument` to load the data and then manipulate it.

Your code should look something like this:

```
Dim xmlTree As XElement = _
            <user>
<user_name>example</user_name>
<user_website>http://myawesomesite.com</user_website>
<user_email>oh@dear.com</user_email>
<user_location>New York</user_location>
</user>

For Each element in xmlTree.Elements()
   Console.WriteLine(element)
Next
```

To get to specific nodes, you would use something like:

```
Dim username as String = xmlTree.Elements("user_name")
```

*My VB skills are a bit rusty and I'm not at a computer with Visual Studio installed, so this code may not be 100% correct, but it should get you in the ballpark.*